# if regex capture contains bracket then capture the contents of bracket else capture the group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following lines...

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/04/11 23:59:52 | 2017-04-11 23:59:52:[ - JmsConsumer[PQ.ACCOUNTS.IN]] JMS01 - Accounts Queue ACCTS1  INFO  Msg Detected
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/04/11 23:59:52 | 2017-04-11 23:59:52:[          default-workqueue-14] sendSoapTarget                 INFO  RESPONSE: <soap:Envelope
```

I created a regex

```
/(?:.*)(?:\| )(?:.*)(?:\| )(.*)(?:\| )(?:.*)(\:\[.*\[?.*\]?\])(?:\s)(.{30})/g
```

[image]

### [image]

In Group #2 - how can I modify the regex to capture the following

- IF Group#2 Contains second set of brackets [ ]
- THEN Capture the contents of the brackets
- ELSE Capture the contents of the group

And get the result:

- Line 1: group #2: PQ.ACCOUNTS.IN
- Line 2: group #2: default-workqueue-14

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how can extract that from group #2. i dont want to capture :[ - JmsConsumer or any text that appears outside bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use non-capturing groups to do your bidding - by first selecting the outer brackets and then trying to find if there are inner brackets in the selection and capture what's between them, or to just capture what's between the outer brackets:

```
(?:\[(?:.*?\[(.*?)\].*?|(.*?))\])
```

You didn't specify what language you use, but this will return you two groups - in case of the `Line 1` the first capturing group will contain the captured string, in case of the `Line 2` the second capturing group will contain what's between the brackets. In both cases there will be only one capturing group populated.

Comment: thank you random internet person. you are amazing. regular expressions are ridiculous and incredible power at same time.